# Find all possible values of rank(A) as a varies?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 2 & -1 \\
        3 & 3 & -2 \\
        -2 & -1 & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I started to reduce the matrix but got stuck. Is there another way to do this problem or can someone help me further reduce this. So far this is what I did

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2/a & -1/a \\
        3 & 3 & -2 \\
        -2 & -1 & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2/a & -1/a \\
        0 & 3-(6/a) & -2+(3/a) \\
        -2 & -1 & a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2/a & -1/a \\
        0 & 3-(6/a) & -2+(3/a) \\
        0 & -1+(4/a) & a-(2/a) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is where I have become stuck. I don't know how to get rid of $-1+(4/a)$.

Comment: Only one tip: DON'T divide by $a$.
First of all, it often makes you forget about the case $a=0$, but also it makes the operations more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My computer algebra system calculates that the characteristic polynomial is
$$ t^3 - (2a+3)t^2 + (a^2 +6a - 10)t - (3a^2 -8a + 5). $$
If $3a^2-8a+5\neq 0$ then the matrix has full rank. Now, $3a^2-8a+5$ has two roots, $1$ and $5/3$. These are not roots of $a^2+6a-10$, so for these values of $a$, the matrix has rank two.

Comment: Nice but I think he ask for algebraic solution

Comment: Calculate the determinant, which is $3a^2-8a+5$. If the determinant is non-zero then the matrix has full rank. Checking the two roots $1,5/3$, we find out that the matrix has rank two.

Comment: Now I and he get one, thanks

Comment: How do you check the roots?

Comment: You substitute $a=1$ and $a=5/3$, and then you find two linearly independent rows in each case. You'll have to do this part yourself.