# Finding all possible ranks of matrix $A$ as $a$ varies?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm working through my linear algebra book and I'm having trouble with one of the questions. After searching for a bit on Google I found that someone else was having trouble with the same part and actually asked a question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948597/find-all-possible-values-of-ranka-as-a-varies). However, I don't think the answer is very clear (but I did use his method to try and solve the question), so I would like to confirm this is the correct way to do it.

Find all possible values of $rank(A)$ as $a$ varies:

$$
A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & a \\
        -2 & 4a & 2 \\
        a & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$

$$ 
det(A) = -4a^3+12a+8
$$
Which gives
$$
\begin{cases}
a = -1\\
a = 2
\end{cases}
$$
Substituting these in matrix $A$ and row reducing gives the two matrices

$$
(a=-1) = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2 & -1 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}
,%   
(a=2) = \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 1 \\[0.3em]
      0 &  1 &  \frac{1}{2} \\[0.3em]
      0 &  0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}   
$$

And so if $a=-1$, then $rank(A) = 1$ and if $a=2$, then $rank(A)=2$. I assume this is the correct way to do this? The book also includes this is the answer: for $a \neq -1,2,$ $rank(A)=3$. Is this found by simply substituting $a$ with an arbitrary number that $\neq -1,2$, so for example $a=1$?

Comment: If $a\ne -1,2$, $\det A\ne 0$, hence the matrix is invertible, and it has maximal rank.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $a\neq -1,2$ $det(A)\neq 0$ therefore the matrix is invertible and the rank is $3$. Indeed $$
A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & a \\
        -2 & 4a & 2 \\
        a & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$

$$ 
det(A) = -4a^3+12a+8
$$ 
If $a=-1$ the rank is $1$, if $a=2$ the rank is $2$

Comment: "f a=−1 the rank is 1, if a=2 the rank is 2". Did you deduce this by obtaining a row-reduced echelon form after assigning a value to a? Explain.