# Finding rank(a) as a varies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

[image]

I computed the determinant to $D= a^{3} - 27a-54$.
When I solve $D=0$, I get $a=6$ and $a=-3$
Now when I plug in these values and bring the matrix to rref, I end up with the identity matrix, both for $a=6$ and $a=-3$.
That's confusing because that would mean the matrix $A$ has $rank=3$ for all values of $a$, and that can't be. So what is going on here?

EDIT: I have already looked at similar questions so please don't mark this as duplicate. From those questions I have understood how to solve this, so that is not the problem. I took the route involving determinants but it gave me results that weren't expected. I have checked the algebra quite a few times and it always seems to come down to this, so I'm posting in the hope that someone can tell me what's wrong.

Comment: I already went through all similar questions. I applied the technique that I learnt from there.

Comment: If I may ask, what is $k$ in your determinant? It should only depend on $a$. For rref see the duplicate. You just may have made an error in the calculation. It goes exactly as done in the duplicate.

Comment: k is a! fixed it.

Comment: your D is wrong it should give a=3 its not the case

Comment: The characteristic polynomial has roots $-6,3$.

Comment: what is the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the characteristic polynomial? Because we haven't done that yet. I am doing exactly what OP is doing and what is suggested in the answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664306/finding-all-possible-ranks-of-matrix-a-as-a-varies?lq=1

Comment: got it! it was a sign mistake