# Find all possible values of rank(A) as 'a' varies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For an assignment I have to solve the following problem:

Find all possible values of rank(A) as 'a' varies:

\begin{bmatrix}a&2&-1\\3&3&-2\\-2&-1&a\end{bmatrix}

I came across several answers on google and stack ([Find all possible values of rank(A) as a varies?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948597/find-all-possible-values-of-ranka-as-a-varies), and similar question, different matrix: [Finding all possible ranks of matrix $A$ as $a$ varies?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664306/finding-all-possible-ranks-of-matrix-a-as-a-varies?lq=1)) but I need to solve the problem using row reduction instead of calculating the determinant. How do I go about?

I'm stuck here:

swapping rows gives:
\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1&a\\3&3&-2\\a&2&-1\end{bmatrix}

reducing rows 2 and 3 gives:

\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1&a\\0&\frac{3}{2}&-2+\frac{3}{2}a\\\\0&2-\frac{1}{2}a&-1+\frac{1}{2}a^2\end{bmatrix}

How to proceed from here?

according to [Find all possible values of rank(A) as a varies?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948597/find-all-possible-values-of-ranka-as-a-varies) the answer should be: rank = 2 for a = 1 or a = 5/3 for all other values rank = 3.

Comment: If you row reduce one more time, you should get your answer.  Then, the matrix will be upper triangular and you'll only need to look at the bottom right corner to see the rank.  (If the value in the bottom right corner is nonzero, then the rank is $3$ and if the value in the bottom right corner is zero, then the rank is $2$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is correct. Now multiply the second row by $\frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{2}a-2)$ and sum to the third line, so you find an upper triangular matrix:
$$
\begin {bmatrix}
-2&-1&a\\
0&\frac{3}{2}&-2+\frac{3}{2}a\\
0&0&a^2-\frac{8}{3}a+\frac{5}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If  $a^2-\frac{8}{3}a+\frac{5}{3} \ne 0$ the matrix is full rank, and this is done if $a$ is different from 1, and $\frac{5}{3}$ (the roots of $a^2-\frac{8}{3}a+\frac{5}{3} = 0$ ). 
Substituting these values you see that the other two rows are linearly independent so the rank of the matrix is $2$ for $a=1$ or $a=\frac{5}{3}$.

Comment: thanks! Problem solved! By accident I posted the question with an unregistered account and now i can't upvote your answer... maybe some mods can help?